# Redirect to a specific link if I click on 'SharePoint start page' icon

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, global-navigation, home-site, sharepoint-app-bar

As the title says, I was wondering if I can **redirect to a specific link or SharePoint site if I click on the 'SharePoint start page' icon**.

Currently, it redirects to the start page where I can see frequent and suggested sites. However, I would like to redirect to a specific SharePoint site whenever I click on the logo. Would appreciate your help.

I am using SharePoint Online and I attached an image of the 'SharePoint start page' icon for more clarification.

[image: SharePoint start page logo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first tab in app bar is a "Global navigation" tab. When global navigation is disabled or not configured, the default home icon redirects to the SharePoint start page.

You cannot redirect it to a specific link or SharePoint site directly. However, you can enable the global navigation & add navigation links which can be redirected to any link or SharePoint site.

Follow below articles for more information and steps to enable & customize global navigation in SharePoint:

1. [Introducing a SharePoint app bar that features global navigation](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/02/24/introducing-a-sharepoint-app-bar-that-features-global-navigation/)
2. [Enable and Customize Global navigation in the SharePoint app bar](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/04/04/enable-and-customize-global-navigation-in-the-sharepoint-app-bar/)

---

**Update from comments**:

To enable & customize the global navigation, you have to set up a home site in SharePoint online tenant. You can set up home site using either of option below:

1. [Set up a home site in SharePoint Online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/03/17/set-up-a-home-site-in-sharepoint-online/)
2. [Set up a SharePoint home site from the SharePoint admin center](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/10/22/set-up-a-sharepoint-home-site-from-the-sharepoint-admin-center/)

**Note**:

1. If you set up a home site first time OR switch your home site to a different site, it might take up to 2 hours for the changes to take effect.
2. You can find the global navigation options from the "Home site" settings.
3. You need Site owner (or higher) permissions on the "home site".

Comment: Thank you so much for that. Unfortunately, I don't see the global navigation option from the settings gear. Is that a permission issue? I have a root site setup already and I've been given owner access to it, which means that this is my home site right? 

Sorry for the newbie questions, just trying to get my head around it

Comment: See updated answer for more information.

Comment: Working beautifully, many thanks!